# What is the minimum effective dose of running that constitutes HIIT?

Tags: running, hiit

I've been doing Cooper runs (1.5 miles) as fast add I can 2-3 times per week, followed by an upper body workout (I know, friends don't let friends skip leg day).

How can I determine whether that constitutes HIIT? Is that simply a function of heart rate and duration? If so, what are the parameters?

Comment: Check out the questions tagged "hiit", see http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hiit A popular for of "time minimalistic" hiit is tabata

Answer (score 2):

Technically, HIIT is defined as: Working out for no longer than 30 minutes at a period of high intensity, and a period of low intensity and repeating the process a number of times.

Running and then lifting is more inline with circuit training (working one muscle group followed by another with little to no rest).

A good example of a HIIT routine would be sprinting than walking/jogging and then sprinting x amount of times within a 30 minute window. There is no rest, just a combination of low and high intensity training. Breaks are not considered low intensity.